# Volumetrics material not showing in final render (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, volumetrics

I have a scene with a sphere that has a Volume Scatter (Anisotropy 1; Density 0.1) material. When I preview it in the viewport (at 750 samples), it seems to be in the scene fine and how I like it. However, when I render the scene, the sphere just disappears, removing that volumetric effect I want.

I made sure it wasn't on a separate render layer or anything. I've done lots of research and nothing has helped.

I appreciate answers in advance!

[image]

Comment: Assuming the sphere in question is `Sphere.006`, I can still see it in the render just fine. Can you see it if you append/copy/paste it into a new scene?